# "Is she is looking/looks so bad" and "I still seeing her"

Tags: gerunds

I have two questions. The first one is: I have heard that I can't use emotional verbs such as "see, hear, love" with -ing, but I want to know how to use it in this sentence:

> Yeah, I still seeing her?

After still, do I use -ing like this?

> I still loving her.

Do I use

> She is looking so bad.

or

> She looks so bad.

The second question is: can I say

> She has to has.

or

> She has to have.

Comment: Can you tell use where you learned that we can't use the gerund of verbs like _see, hear, love,_ etc.? _Loving, seeing,_ and _hearing_ are perfectly correct English gerunds. (We do not use **wanna** in polite English. It is only acceptable in informal settings such as text messaging among friends. Use **want to** instead.)

Comment: In your own language, it may be correct to say _She happy,_ but English is not the same as your native language. We use the copula or linking verb in sentences like _She **is** happy_ and _I **am** still loving her._ Have you studied the _linking verbs_ like _to be?_

Comment: You shouldn't add information like " I have heard that..." since by itself it is not helpful. You should focus on learning correct English, not copying what someone says which may or may not be correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think the rule you were taught is that you ought not to use the *-ing* form of "emotional" verbs in the *present progressive* tense. In English, the verbs "to see", "to hear", "to feel" are not really "emotional", though.  I'm not sure how best to categorize these *verbs of perception* if you group them with "emotional" verbs like "loving".

Moreover there's nothing wrong with using verbs like "to look" or "to listen" in the progressive tense. Remember when using the progressive tense you **must** use *is* or *are* in the sentence.  Examples:

> I **am looking** but I don't see her.
>
> Shh!  **I'm listening** to the orchestra.

As with many English words, these verbs have alternate meanings which you may use in the progressive tense.  "To see" someone could mean to "to date" someone.  If you say, for example:

> **Are** you still **seeing** her?

you are asking if the person still regularly goes on *dates* with her.  I suggest you look up some of the other words on your list to see if they also have alternate meanings.

The progressive tense indicates a current, ongoing action.  If you want to talk about someone's condition, you should use the simple present instead:

> She **looks** very nice today.
>
> I **hear** he got a new job.
>
> I **see** that they are still dating.

---

As for your second question, the "has to/have to" structure (to indicate some kind of *necessity*) is followed by the bare [*infinitive*](http://www.gingersoftware.com/content/grammar-rules/nouns/gerunds-infinitives/) form of the verb.

> I have **to go**
>
> I have **to sleep**
>
> I have **to eat.**
>
> She has **to study.**

This holds true even if the very is "to have":

> We have **to have** new clothes if we want to go to that club.
>
> She has **to have** some better music on her phone.
>
> They have **to have** a vacation soon.

It may sound weird to say "have to have", but to native English speakers it sounds perfectly natural.

Comment: These verbs are called _verbs of perception._ You might consider replacing _I'm not sure how best to categorize them_ with the commonly used term.

Comment: @P.E.Dant edited my answer.  I meant that I don't know how to categorize them if you lump them in with verbs like *loving*.

Comment: _See_ and _hear_ et al. are _verbs of perception._ _Love, hate, like_ et al. are _stative verbs of emotion._ Both kinds of verb (and some others) fail to play well with the present continuous—we don't usually say _"I am hating that"_ or _"I am seeing it,"_ which I think is what the OP means by the reference to _-ing_ forms.

Answer (score 0):

Your question on using see, hear and love in

> Yeah, I still seeing her?

can be either "Yeah, I still see her" or "Yeah, I am still seeing her".  Adding the word *am* allows the use of the -ing, but the way the sentences are understood is slightly different.

> I still see her

is a statement of fact in the present, but

> I am still seeing her

is a statement of fact in the "progressive aspect", meaning that it refers to an action that is in the middle of happening.

This might be easier to understand with other verbs.  "I am eating" means that I am in the middle of eating right now, while "I eat" is more of a general statement -- "I eat vegetables every day."

With

> I still loving her

to be clear on meaning it can only be

> I still love her

The reason is that "I am still loving her" can have mixed meanings depending on how and when it is said.

With your question on whether you can use "She is looking so bad" or "She looks so bad", you can use either sentence and mean the same thing, although in slightly different ways.  Again this is in the terms of "statement of fact" and "within the progressive aspect".

The answer to your second question is

> She has to have

The main verb **to have** implies the meaning of possession the auxiliary verb **She has** is used to help the main verb create the perfect tense.

The auxiliary verbs for **to have** in the context of

> **I** or **you** or **we** or **they**

are

> **have** in the present tense or **had** in the past tense

The auxiliary verbs for **to have** in the context of

> **he** or **she** or **it**

are

> **has** in the present tense or **have** in the past tense.